# Configure Capifony

Tags: deployment, symfony, capifony

I'm trying to configure Capifony on my server to deploy a symfony2 project but when i launch

```
cap deploy
```

i get this error:

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320110954 && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod'" on myserver.home
```

This is my deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "nov-ita"
set :domain,      "root@myserver.home"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/vhosts/nov-ita"
set :app_path,    "app"
set :user,        "root"
set :use_sudo,    false

set :scm,         :subversion 
set :repository,  "svn://server.home/novita2/trunk"
set :scm_username, "myuser"
set :scm_password, "mypass"
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `doctrine`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Rails migrations will run

set  :keep_releases,  1

set :deploy_via, :rsync_with_remote_cache

# directories that will be shared between all deployments
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor", web_path + "/images/cached"]
```

I have installed on both server (local and remote) rsync and svn and ssh access on the remote server works fine.
Any idea??

UPDATE:
As suggested i insert 
    set :update_vendors,    true
in my deploy.rb and now i get this output

```
          * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "svn info svn://server.home/novita2/trunk --username myuser --password mypass --no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
    command finished in 62ms
    executing locally: svn switch -q --username myuser --password mypass --no-auth-cache  -r216 svn://server.home/novita2/trunk /var/www/vhosts/novita2/jury/.rsync_cache
    command finished in 195ms
    executing locally: rsync -az --delete --rsh='ssh -p 22' /var/www/vhosts/novita2/jury/.rsync_cache/ root@myserver.home:/var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/cached-copy/
root@myserver.home's password: 
    command finished in 621673ms
  * executing "rsync -a --delete /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/cached-copy/ /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
Password: 
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'rsync -a --delete /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/cached-copy/ /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/'
    command finished in 1043ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'chmod -R g+w /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556'
    command finished in 317ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache; fi'
    command finished in 265ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache && chmod -R 0777 /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache && chmod -R 0777 /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache'
    command finished in 265ms
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'chmod -R g+w /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/cache'
    command finished in 266ms
  * executing `deploy:share_childs'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs'
    command finished in 266ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs; fi'
    command finished in 267ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs'
    command finished in 265ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads'
    command finished in 271ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads; fi'
    command finished in 276ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads'
    command finished in 301ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor'
    command finished in 325ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor; fi'
    command finished in 313ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor'
    command finished in 252ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached'
    command finished in 160ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached; fi'
    command finished in 168ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached'
    command finished in 183ms
  * executing "if [ -d web/css ] ; then mkdir -p web/css; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d web/css ] ; then mkdir -p web/css; fi'
    command finished in 175ms
  * executing "if [ -d web/images ] ; then mkdir -p web/images; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d web/images ] ; then mkdir -p web/images; fi'
    command finished in 171ms
  * executing "if [ -d web/js ] ; then mkdir -p web/js; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d web/js ] ; then mkdir -p web/js; fi'
    command finished in 172ms
  * executing "find /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/css /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/js -exec touch -t 201203201336.59 {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] env TZ=UTC sh -c 'find /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/css /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/js -exec touch -t 201203201336.59 {} '\'';'\''; true'
*** [err :: myserver.home] find:
*** [err :: myserver.home] `/var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/js'
*** [err :: myserver.home] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
    command finished in 603ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing `deploy:share_childs'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs'
    command finished in 155ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs; fi'
    command finished in 155ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/app/logs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/logs'
    command finished in 155ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads'
    command finished in 152ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads; fi'
    command finished in 162ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/uploads /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/uploads'
    command finished in 156ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor'
    command finished in 160ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor; fi'
    command finished in 155ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/vendor /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor'
    command finished in 153ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached'
    command finished in 160ms
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached; fi"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached ] ; then rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached; fi'
    command finished in 154ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'ln -nfs /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/shared/web/images/cached /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/web/images/cached'
    command finished in 157ms
  * executing `symfony:vendors:reinstall'
  * executing "cd /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556 && php bin/vendors install --reinstall"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'cd /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556 && php bin/vendors install --reinstall'
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating symfony
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/symfony
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/symfony
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/symfony
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating twig
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/twig
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/twig
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/twig
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating monolog
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/monolog
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/monolog
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/monolog
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating doctrine-common
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine-common
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine-common
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine-common
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating doctrine-dbal
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine-dbal
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine-dbal
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine-dbal
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating doctrine
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/doctrine
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating swiftmailer
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/swiftmailer
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/swiftmailer
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/swiftmailer
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating assetic
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/assetic
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/assetic
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/assetic
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating twig-extensions
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/twig-extensions
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/twig-extensions
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/twig-extensions
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating metadata
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/metadata
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/metadata
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/metadata
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating JMSSecurityExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating SensioDistributionBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating SensioGeneratorBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating AsseticBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
 ** [out :: myserver.home] > Installing/Updating GregwarImageBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] git: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Gregwar/ImageBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Gregwar/ImageBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] cd: 1:
*** [err :: myserver.home] can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Gregwar/ImageBundle
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] sh:
*** [err :: myserver.home] /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php: not found
*** [err :: myserver.home] 
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/autoload.php on line 44
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP Stack trace:
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/console:0
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   2. require_once() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/console:10
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   3. require_once() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/autoload.php on line 44
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP Stack trace:
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/console:0
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   2. require_once() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/console:10
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   3. require_once() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3
    command finished in 574ms
  * executing `symfony:assets:install'
  * executing "cd /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556 && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'cd /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556 && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod'
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/autoload.php on line 44
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP Stack trace:
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/console:0
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   2. require_once() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/console:10
*** [err :: myserver.home] PHP   3. require_once() /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3
    command finished in 212ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556; true"
    servers: ["myserver.home"]
    [myserver.home] executing command
    [myserver.home] sh -c 'rm -rf /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556; true'
    command finished in 273ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556 && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod'" on myserver.home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use

```
set :update_vendors,    true
```

So that the vendors get installed.

Comment: Do you see the vendors installation occurring in the log?

Comment: i searched in prod.log and dev.log but i have not found nothing...i was looking the terminal output and after i add update vendors now i get some line like that:
"can't cd to /var/www/vhosts/nov-ita/releases/20120320133556/vendor//bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle"

Comment: I was talking about the terminal ouput

Comment: Maybe you should update your post with the output you're getting now.

Comment: And maybe you should run the setup task again (not sure at all).

Comment: PS: i haven't git installed on my server...may be this the cause of the error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9093/discussion-between-jury89-and-greg0ire)